# Why is fluid not entering this hollow object?

Tags: fluid-simulation

Pouring water into a cup.
The cup does not have a lid, but the following situation is shown.
How can I solve this problem?

Here is the .blend file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=10zGUdGM0ecQkPkBijZ9jlZcaX9kja24Y
Here is video that show the problem: https://youtu.be/mONqiAtMlwQ

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: `Volume Initialization` of obstacle should be `Shell` for such simulation

Comment: @SergeL You should make that as an answer, instead of a comment, as it does solves the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps its the issue of Volume Initialization of obstacle being set as Volume instead of shell.
Volume- considers the obstacle(although with a hole) as a whole block and bakes the simulation likewise.
shell- considers the cutoff portion and bakes what's required to.
[image]